# Continuous ripple animation - Android

Tags: android, svg, material-design, animatedvectordrawable

Is it possible to add a continuous ripple effect behind an icon which can be show/hide programmatically?

The icon is set as an end icon drawable on TextInpuLayout.

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below code,

```
public class RippleBackground extends RelativeLayout{

    private static final int DEFAULT_RIPPLE_COUNT=6;
    private static final int DEFAULT_DURATION_TIME=3000;
    private static final float DEFAULT_SCALE=6.0f;
    private static final int DEFAULT_FILL_TYPE=0;

    private int rippleColor;
    private float rippleStrokeWidth;
    private float rippleRadius;
    private int rippleDurationTime;
    private int rippleAmount;
    private int rippleDelay;
    private float rippleScale;
    private int rippleType;
    private Paint paint;
    private boolean animationRunning=false;
    private AnimatorSet animatorSet;
    private ArrayList<Animator> animatorList;
    private LayoutParams rippleParams;
    private ArrayList<RippleView> rippleViewList=new ArrayList<RippleView>();

    public RippleBackground(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RippleBackground(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public RippleBackground(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (isInEditMode())
            return;

        if (null == attrs) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Attributes should be provided to this view,");
        }

        final TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RippleBackground);
        rippleColor=typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.RippleBackground_rb_color, getResources().getColor(R.color.rippelColor));
        rippleStrokeWidth=typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.RippleBackground_rb_strokeWidth, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.rippleStrokeWidth));
        rippleRadius=typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.RippleBackground_rb_radius,getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.rippleRadius));
        rippleDurationTime=typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.RippleBackground_rb_duration,DEFAULT_DURATION_TIME);
        rippleAmount=typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.RippleBackground_rb_rippleAmount,DEFAULT_RIPPLE_COUNT);
        rippleScale=typedArray.getFloat(R.styleable.RippleBackground_rb_scale,DEFAULT_SCALE);
        rippleType=typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.RippleBackground_rb_type,DEFAULT_FILL_TYPE);
        typedArray.recycle();

        rippleDelay=rippleDurationTime/rippleAmount;

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        if(rippleType==DEFAULT_FILL_TYPE){
            rippleStrokeWidth=0;
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        }else
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(rippleColor);

        rippleParams=new LayoutParams((int)(2*(rippleRadius+rippleStrokeWidth)),(int)(2*(rippleRadius+rippleStrokeWidth)));
        rippleParams.addRule(CENTER_IN_PARENT, TRUE);

        animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        animatorList=new ArrayList<Animator>();

        for(int i=0;i<rippleAmount;i++){
            RippleView rippleView=new RippleView(getContext());
            addView(rippleView,rippleParams);
            rippleViewList.add(rippleView);
             final ObjectAnimator scaleXAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rippleView, "ScaleX", 1.0f, rippleScale);
            scaleXAnimator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
            scaleXAnimator.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.RESTART);
            scaleXAnimator.setStartDelay(i * rippleDelay);
            scaleXAnimator.setDuration(rippleDurationTime);
            animatorList.add(scaleXAnimator);
            final ObjectAnimator scaleYAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rippleView, "ScaleY", 1.0f, rippleScale);
            scaleYAnimator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
            scaleYAnimator.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.RESTART);
            scaleYAnimator.setStartDelay(i * rippleDelay);
            scaleYAnimator.setDuration(rippleDurationTime);
            animatorList.add(scaleYAnimator);
            final ObjectAnimator alphaAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rippleView, "Alpha", 1.0f, 0f);
            alphaAnimator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
            alphaAnimator.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.RESTART);
            alphaAnimator.setStartDelay(i * rippleDelay);
            alphaAnimator.setDuration(rippleDurationTime);
            animatorList.add(alphaAnimator);
        }

        animatorSet.playTogether(animatorList);
    }

    private class RippleView extends View{

        public RippleView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            int radius=(Math.min(getWidth(),getHeight()))/2;
            canvas.drawCircle(radius,radius,radius-rippleStrokeWidth,paint);
        }
    }

    public void startRippleAnimation(){
        if(!isRippleAnimationRunning()){
            for(RippleView rippleView:rippleViewList){
                rippleView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            }
            animatorSet.start();
            animationRunning=true;
        }
    }

    public void stopRippleAnimation(){
        if(isRippleAnimationRunning()){
            animatorSet.end();
            animationRunning=false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isRippleAnimationRunning(){
        return animationRunning;
    }
}
```

in attrs.xml file add this ,

```
<declare-styleable name="RippleBackground">
        <attr name="rb_color" format="color" />
        <attr name="rb_strokeWidth" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="rb_radius" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="rb_duration" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="rb_rippleAmount" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="rb_scale" format="float"/>
        <attr name="rb_type" format="enum">
            <enum name="fillRipple" value="0"/>
            <enum name="strokeRipple" value="1"/>
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
```

add color in color.xml file

```
<color name="rippelColor">#0099CC</color>
```

add dimension in dimen.xml file

```
<dimen name="rippleStrokeWidth">2dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="rippleRadius">64dp</dimen>
```

After adding above code just start animation like this in your activity

```
rippleBackground.startRippleAnimation();
```

Comment: I would like the icon to be animated.